# Express 4, how to see all cookies being sent in res

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, response

Hi all i'm using Express 4 with cookie-parser. For some reason the cookie is being set in the `res` object, but is not really stored in the browser. I wanted to see ALL cookies that are about to be passed at the end (all cookies for the current `response` object). Any idea on how to get them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
console.log('Cookies: ', res._headers["set-cookie"]);
```

Explanation: As the cookies are set in the response header as "*set-cookie*" attribute.